# Restricting "every nth point" to a domain

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a plot with a *lot* of data points, but most of the plot doesn't need the level of detail in the data.

How can I combine `each nth point` and `restrict expr to domain`?

I want to apply `each nth point=3` between the domains `x=0:9` and `x=28:36`. Preferably while also plotting end point at `x=36`, because it would be skipped by otherwise blindly plotting every third point.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=8cm,
height=5cm,
scale only axis,
]
\addplot [
color=red,
solid,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
0 1\\
1 2\\
2 3\\
3 4\\
4 5\\
6 7\\
7 8\\
8 9\\
9 10\\
10 18\\
14 4\\
18 30\\
20 45\\
22 2\\
24 15\\
28 10\\
29 9\\
30 8\\
31 7\\
32 6\\
33 5\\
34 4\\
35 3\\
36 2\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotstableread{
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
6 7
7 8
8 9
9 10
10 18
14 4
18 30
20 45
22 2
24 15
28 10
29 9
30 8
31 7
32 6
33 5
34 4
35 3
36 2
}\mytable
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=8cm,
height=5cm,
scale only axis,
]
\addplot [
color=red,
mark=*,
solid,
each nth point={3},
restrict x to domain=0:9,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{\mytable};
\addplot [
color=red,
mark=*,
solid,
each nth point={3},
restrict x to domain=28:36,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{\mytable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Close! But there are a couple of issues. I need to add 34:36 manually in another `\addplot`. The biggest problem is my data: I have ~300 sets of data embedded in `\addplot` tables (like my question). All the sets of data overlap in places, which is where it's not necessary to plot all the points. It's not trivial to reorganize the file to use `\pgfplotstableread`. Granted it's not a huge issue, I'm just trying to minimize file sizes and avoid bogging down the PDF rendering speed.